# How to allow scroll on mobile

Tags: css, responsive-design

Good morning,

I have a problem with scrolling my website on mobiles. I have set div height to 100%, but on mobile, it has height 'auto'. But still, when text is longer than the screen height, I am unable to read it. How should I edit it please? Thank you!

HTML:

```
<div id="about">

<div id="onas">
<div id="obsah">
<p> text text text....</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#about {
background:url('images/bg-about.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;

    min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
    color: white;

  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
z-index: 1;
}

#obsah {
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 10%;
margin-top: 5%;
color: black;
font-size: 21px;
}

#onas {
position: absolute;
font-family: cond;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  min-height: 40%;
}

 @media screen and (max-width: 1024px){

#onas {
position: static;
margin-top: 200px;
padding-top: 15px;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
min-height: 40%;
}

}
```

Comment: Try add into `#onas` `overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto;`

Comment: it didn't work for me..:/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have:

> position: fixed;

In your about, you were probably trying to apply it to the background.

Delete that line and it will scroll.

[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: I've tried it, but I still can't scroll on mobile. The problem is not in the height I think, but somewhere in the code must be specified that the height is EXACTLY 100% and you can't exceed it. So the text on mobile screen is to the half of its lenght and I can't scroll to finish reading it...